# Drawing library for C#

Tags: c#, drawing, directx

Will someone please point me the way to the best 2D drawing library that can be used in C#?  I started to look into System.Drawing.Drawing2D but then I read that I should use DirectX for best performance.  I've found the DirectX SDK but it is version 9.  Isn't version 11 the latest?  I'm attempting to create a somewhat simple 2D application for a PC.  The only thing that makes it complicated is that I'm needed to draw a large number of simple moving objects (~100,000) on a 2D map.  So, I'm betting performance is important.

Comment: dX doesn't work on C#, you need something like http://sharpdx.org/ or XNA.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/), which actually provides wrappers for Direct2D.  This will provide access to the "best" (or at least most current) hardware accelerated 2D drawing API for Microsoft platforms.

Answer (score 3):

The 'best' is not that concrete. I'm partial to [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) or something like XNA if it is a game or simulation.

Comment: I read about XNA but heard it will soon be dead.  I'll look into OpenTK and SharpDX.

Comment: Well, there's an open source remake of XNA called MonoGame, it's another thing to consider.

Comment: Yes, and the MonoGame community is definitely keeping it alive by continuing to support it for every possible platform; even Windows 8 which XNA can no longer be installed easily on! I think they even support Xbox.